# Combining variables in a data frame based on factor levels from another data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
head(Diets)
  Sp1  Sp2  Sp3  Sp4  Sp5
1 0.4  0.4  0.1  0.2  0.0
2 1.4  0.1  0.1  0.3  3.4
3 0.5  0.6  0.1  0.4  0.0
....
```

I would like to create a new dataframe that sums these values based on their membership in groups (factor) from another dataframe:

```
head(Groups)    
    SpName    GroupName
1   Sp1       Grp1
2   Sp2       Grp1
3   Sp3       Grp2
4   Sp4       Grp3
5   Sp5       Grp3
....
```

to get this:

```
   Grp1 Grp2 Grp3
1  0.8  0.1  0.2
2  1.5  0.1  3.7
3  1.1  0.1  0.4
```

Comment: Please provide a *reproducible* example.

Comment: This could be a good question, it just needs a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Although perhaps not clear, the portions shown are a viable example.

Comment: @MtGoat77 Please consider to post the data in a reproducible form as shown in the answer below, you could do that by using `dput` like this `dput(your.data.here)` and copy-paste the result here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using base R's `aggregate` function

**Step1** Put together both the data.frames

```
data = data.frame(cbind(df1, t(df2)))
```

**Step2** perform summation of the values corresponding to each group

```
out = aggregate(cbind(X1, X2,  X3) ~ V3 , data, sum)
```

**Step3** put the output as desired by transposing and setting the column names using `setNames`

```
setNames(data.frame(t(out[,-1]),row.names = NULL), out[,1])

#  Grp1 Grp2 Grp3
#1  0.8  0.1  0.2
#2  1.5  0.1  3.7
#3  1.1  0.1  0.4
```

**data**

```
df1 = structure(list(V1 = 1:5, V2 = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Sp1", 
"Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp5"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Grp1", "Grp2", "Grp3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 = structure(list(Sp1 = c(0.4, 1.4, 0.5), Sp2 = c(0.4, 0.1, 0.6), 
    Sp3 = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), Sp4 = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4), Sp5 = c(0, 
    3.4, 0)), .Names = c("Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
groups <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
text="SpName    GroupName
1   Sp1       Grp1
2   Sp2       Grp1
3   Sp3       Grp2
4   Sp4       Grp3
5   Sp5       Grp3")

diets <- read.table(header = TRUE,
text="Sp1  Sp2  Sp3  Sp4  Sp5
1 0.4  0.4  0.1  0.2  0.0
2 1.4  0.1  0.1  0.3  3.4
3 0.5  0.6  0.1  0.4  0.0")
```

If the colnames of diets are in the same order as in the groups data, you can just use this. Otherwise, `match` would be safer

```
# names(diets) <- groups$GroupName
names(diets) <- groups$GroupName[match(names(diets), groups$SpName)]

sapply(split(names(diets), names(diets)), function(x)
  rowSums(diets[, names(diets) %in% x, drop = FALSE]))

#   Grp1 Grp2 Grp3
# 1  0.8  0.1  0.2
# 2  1.5  0.1  3.7
# 3  1.1  0.1  0.4
```